# How would I convert a raster image to a usable format like jpg?

Tags: ruby, raster-graphics

I have an obscure raster image file format called RVG. It is created from Kodak's carestream sensor. I want to be able to open it for viewing through web software(ruby/rails). We have RMagic installed and use it for other images but this format is not supported. This is the file information for a sample image:

```
 MediaStorage is 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.1.3.1 [Digital Intra-oral X-Ray Image Storage - For Processing]
 TransferSyntax is 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70 [JPEG Lossless, Non-Hierarchical, First-Order Prediction (Process 14 [Selection Value 1]): Default Transfer Syntax for Lossless JPEG Image Compression]
 NumberOfDimensions: 2
 Dimensions: (1200,1600,1)
 SamplesPerPixel    :1
 BitsAllocated      :16
 BitsStored         :12
 HighBit            :11
 PixelRepresentation:0
 ScalarType found   :UINT16
 PhotometricInterpretation: MONOCHROME2 
 PlanarConfiguration: 0
 TransferSyntax: 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70
 Origin: (0,0,0)
 Spacing: (0.0185,0.0185,1)
 DirectionCosines: (1,0,0,0,1,0)
 Rescale Intercept/Slope: (0,1)
 Orientation Label: AXIAL
```

Is there a way to read this image and export as jpg? I understand that Raster Images are basically a grid with color information. Maybe I can read line by line and export?